# Add Facebook App 2 Times to fanpage

Tags: facebook

i have created an app, which u can see online:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Hotel-Des-Balances/302383665689?sk=app_102064213296864

But there i have created tabs inside the iframe, i want to create them directly in facebook, so that i have Tab1 for the Game1, Tab2 for game2 without creating multiple facebook apps!

How can i create multiple add to page ?

Comment: You simply can't add the same application twice to the same page.

Comment: Hi, ok but can i create one iframe application with 3 tabs?